# Getting URL value from HashMap in a JSP page (Using Struts2)

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, hashmap

I am trying to get my page to link to a certain URL that is stored in a HashMap (the key is some name, and the value is the URL I want to link to). I'm not very good at describing this, but here is my code:

For the JSP page:

```
<table>
  <s:iterator value="dependenciesList" id="dependency">
    <tr><td>
    <a href="<s:url value="productDocumentationMap.getKey(%{dependency})"/>">
    <s:property value="dependency"/> </a>
    </td></tr>
  </s:iterator> 
  </table>
```

Note: productDocumentationMap is a HashMap of `<String, String>,` and dependenciesList is an `ArrayList<String>`.

For instance, if dependenciesList contains three elements [A, B, C], the first link would link to something like: http:///productDocumentationMap.getKey(A)
but what I want is for the link to be the actual value of

`productDocumentationMap.getKey("A");`

I know I might be doing something stupid (I'm still new to all this Struts2 business), but is there a way I can get my link to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OGNL, you can access a map using "mapName[indexName]", where indexName is the key you want.

e.g.

```
 <a href="<s:url value='productDocumentationMap[#dependency]'/>">
```

I think this is the right syntax for resolving 'dependency' as a variable, instead of as the string 'dependency', but this should call 'getProductDocumentationMap()', and if it returns a Map object, attempt to lookup the **value** of the iterator.  I assume you really want the value, rather than the key, since 'dependency' itself is the key.

This page gives some example OGNL expressions that you might find helpful as a reference.  I find half the time I just end up fiddling with no parenthesis, %{} and/or # until it works.  :-)

http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-ognl-expression-language-example-1.html

---

For your follow-up question:

I use this for testing nulls against simple properties and including a section.  I imagine it could probably be applied to returned values from maps.

```
<s:if test="%{licenseStatusString != null}">
 ... something that uses licenseStatusString
</s:if>
<s:else>
 ... optional thing to include if the license status string is null.
</s:else>
```

maybe

```
<s:if test="%{productDocumentationMap[#dependency] != null}">
```

Try that and see if it works.  Probably some permutation of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot sdeer, this worked for me! On another note, would you happen to know how to create a link only if productDocumentationMap.get(dependency) returns a non-null value? Some of the products don't have any links, so I don't want to create a hyperlink to non-existent pages. Thanks a lot!

Comment: moved the comment into my original answer to preserve formatting

Comment: I ended up using something like:
<s:if test="productDocumentationMap[#dependency] != ''">

(Apparently even if there is no value inside the Map, it won't return null, but it does return an empty String)

Thanks a lot, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: You're welcome.  My knowledge is just stolen from others, really.  I bought this book when Struts 2 was pushed on me, and it's made all the difference.  :-)

http://www.amazon.com/Struts-2-Action-Don-Brown/dp/193398807X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1281380788&sr=8-1